# How are routes refresh/rebuild after they are programmaticaly created?

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I installed the [External Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/external_entities) module, which allows to create an entity and generate its route automatically. I checked what the module does and found the following.

- KernelDesctructionSubscriber.php line 48 --> `public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)`
- ContainerAwareEventDispacther.php line 111 --> `$definition['callable']($event, $event_name, $this);`
- HttpKernel.php Line 84 --> `$this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, new PostResponseEvent($this, $request, $response));`
- StackedHttpKernel.Php Line 32 --> `$kernel->terminate($request, $response);`
- Drupal Kernel Line 634 --> `$this->getHttpKernel()->terminate($request, $response);`
- index.php Line 22 --> `$kernel->terminate($request, $response);`

[`KernelDestructionSubscriber::onKernelTerminate`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21KernelDestructionSubscriber.php/function/KernelDestructionSubscriber%3A%3AonKernelTerminate/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```php
foreach ($this->services as $id) {
  // Check if the service was initialized during this request, destruction
  // is not necessary if the service was not used.
  if ($this->container->initialized($id)) {
    $service = $this->container->get($id);
    $service->destruct();
  }
}
```

when the ID is equal to *drupal.proxy_original_service.router.builder*, it executes  [`Container::initialized()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21DependencyInjection%21Container.php/function/Container%3A%3Ainitialized/8.2.x).

```php
if (isset($this->aliases[$id])) {
  $id = $this->aliases[$id];
}

return isset($this->services[$id]) || array_key_exists($id, $this->services);
```

it will return `TRUE` because `$this->services[$id]` is set, call `$service->destruct()` in `onKernelTerminate()`, and rebuild the route.

Where does the *External Entities* set `$this->services[$id]` and rebuild the routes?

Comment: It might be easier to ask and answer *what you are actually trying to achieve* and explain why you need to know this.

Comment: @Berdir, thanks for replying, to be honest, it is more into understanding how the code works inside Drupal when you create route programatically,, so then i can write the code 'properly'. And the in the core code seems like there is a way for you when you create a route programmatically it will refresh the route automatically that i like to understand how...

Comment: Then you should ask that, explain your use case and what you want to do, that will be a lot easier to answer and will help you more

Comment: Agree with you @Berdir, I have edited my question, i hope that's clear - my objective is to understand how Drupal Core rebuild the route automatically after route created programaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything in the module doing it, but this is done through the router.builder service.

Either rebuild immediately, with `\Drupal::service('router.builder')->rebuild();` or tell it to rebuild at the end of the request, which is `\Drupal::service('router.builder')->setRebuildNeeded()`

Based on what you posted, it looks to me that you went through all the boring, generic stuff and stopped right before if would have gotten interesting, in the `rebuildIfNeeded()` method of that service. It checks the `rebuildNeeded` flag and rebuilds the routes when necessary.

So, you don't have to do anything to have that method called, that happens automatically if the service got invoked, you just have to make sure that flag is set.